# Do perfect squared rectangles with corners of sizes 10, 12 and 13 exist?

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, tiling, packing-problem, constraint-programming

A squared rectangle is a rectangle dissected into squares.
squared rectangles are called perfect if the squares in the tiling are all of different sizes and are positive integers.
The smallest perfect squared rectangle is 33x32 in width and height. [image]

The corners   are the squares 18, 15, 14 and 9.  9 is the smallest known corner in a perfect squared rectangle.  Millions of squared rectangles have been produced, this is the only known example of 9 in a corner.    It is also the only known example of 14 in a corner.  It is conjectured that 9 and 14 are only possible as corners in this arrangement.   PSRs (perfect squared rectangles) have corners sizes from 15 upwards but only one example of a PSR with a corner of 11 is known. It was found by Brian Trial.
http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/51-773x661-11corner.pdf

The corresponding problem for the smallest square on the boundary has been solved by Ian Gambini.  The smallest square possible on the boundary is 5.  PSRs and PSSs (perfect squared squares) exist with squares on the boundary with sides of 5 and above. http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/5-side-spss.png

Brian Trial also found 3 PSRs with 5 on the boundary
http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/o28-5-side.txt1pp.pdf (you need to zoom in to see the small squares)

No examples of PSRs with corners of 10, 12 and 13 are known.

Are they even possible?

I have generated whole orders of PSRs, over 300 million squared rectangles, all the way from order 9 up to 24 squares and have not found any with corners of 10,11,12,13.
Brian Trial has different packing software and has found the order 51 PSR with the 11 corner but nothing else is known, to my knowledge.

Any suggestions, or useful software would be most welcome.